# Custom format cell to consider dash as zero in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I import data from web external query in excel in which zero value represented as dash, to further calculation on this I need to consider this dash as zero

for that I have macro to convert dash to zero but, data gets refreshed every 5 min. so I need to run that replacement macro every 5 min.

instead of this I want to do is,apply format cell in which dash will be considered as zero and I will import data by selecting preserve format, so no need to run replacement macro every 5 min.

So pls let me know custom format cell in which positive value ll be consider as positive,negative as negative but dashes as zero

thank you.

Comment: Cell formatting only affects the appearance of the cell.  It does not affect how entries into the cell are interpreted.  Perhaps you can do that as part of your query.

Comment: truly said...I am getting it

Answer (score 0):

In your custom format cell use the following format: `#;-#;"-";@`

It decomposes as `positive numbers; negatives; nul value; any text`.
I Commonly use: `#,00;-#,00;"-";@` to set get 2 digit precision.

Access format cells with `right click` > `Format Cells...` > tab `Number` > Category `custom`

Comment: Your custom format displays a zero as a dash.  The OP *need to consider this dash as zero*. I am assuming the dash is in the imported data, and is imported in the query as text.

Comment: Dash is imported data and I have applied this `#;-#;"-";@`  custom format on cells but still it shows as dash

Comment: @Arshitpatel See my comment. This solution cannot work for your problem.

Comment: got it, read too quickly - sorry. The question ask for the impossible, so I assumed the versa.